# Is the question on-topic here (main site, not meta)?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435308/what-is-dev-tty-in-unix#comment28666746_10435447) question on topic on *unix.se.com*:

> what's the application/use of unifying the two API[console API and file API] and providing such a feature[copy file from one terminal to another]?

Comment: This seems like the last sentence of a paragraph; without the rest of it I don't really know what you're talking about

Comment: @MichaelMrozek if you check the previous comment to the link provided the context would be clear. of course I would be more elaborate if it is on topic here.

Comment: Oh, thanks; I didn't notice the link the first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's fine, although I would definitely explain the whole context in the question. Something like:

> It was explained in [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435308/what-is-dev-tty-in-unix) that each logical terminal has a "pseudo-terminal", and that writing to one:
>
> ```
> $ cat some-file.txt > /dev/ttys002
> ```
>
> will cause the data to appear in that terminal window. What's the reason for providing a file-like API to terminal windows? Is there any use case where this is helpful?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/95896/20447